# Getting compliation serror, syntax error

Tags: vbscript

I am running the following script, to uninstall sccm 2007 client, uninstall wds, webdav, remove stale registry entries and folders and then create a .sms file on all the drives except p drive, I want the script to perform actions in an order and should pick from where it stopped after reboot but I get complation error after calling `ccmsetup`. where am I going wrong? Can we call a subroutine in the middle of execution of a script?

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "Software\My Scripts"
strValue = "Componentsuninstallscript"
objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValue,strScriptStatus
If IsNull(strScriptStatus) Then
  strScriptStatus = "Run"
  objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath`enter code here`
  objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValue,strScriptStatus
  call ccmsetup()
  call Wdswebdavuninstall()
  strNewKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
  strNewValue = "Componentsuninstallscript"
  Dim WMIServiceObject, ComputerObject 
  WMIServiceObject = GetObject("Winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Debug,Shutdown)}")
  For Each ComputerObject In WMIServiceObject.InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem") 
    Rebootserver = ComputerObject.Win32Shutdown(2 + 4, 0) 
    If Rebootserver <> 0 Then 
      MsgBox("Sorry, an error has occurred while trying to perform selected operation") 
    Else 
    End If 
  Next
  objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strNewKeyPath,strNewValue,strScriptPath
  Wscript.Quit
End If

Wscript.Echo "Proceeding to remove folders and registry entries."
On error resume next
Dim Strkeypathm(5)
Dim i
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
strKeyPathm(0) = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WDSMC"
Strkeypathm(1) = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WDSTFTP"
StrKeypathm(2) = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCM"
Strkeypathm(3) = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CCMSetup"
Strkeypathm(4) = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\SMS"
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
For i=0 to 4
  DeleteSubkeys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeypathm(i)
Next

Sub DeleteSubkeys(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPathm) 
  objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPathm, arrSubkeys 
  If IsArray(arrSubkeys) Then 
    For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
      DeleteSubkeys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPathm & "\" & strSubkey 
    Next 
  End If 
  objRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPathm

  Call Nosmsondrive()
  Call Removalofflders()
  objRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath

Sub ccmsetup()
  Set wshshell=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
  Wscript.echo "Please Wait while SCCM 2007 client is getting uninstalled"
  ccmuninstall=wshshell.Run("C:\Windows\CCMSetup\ccmsetup.exe" & " " &  "/Uninstall",0,True)
  Set objfso=Createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  Set ccmsetuplog=objfso.opentextfile("C:\Windows\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.log",1)
  Do Until ccmsetuplog.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = ccmsetuplog.ReadLine
    If strNextLine="Uninstall succeeded." Then
      Wscript.echo "SCCM 2007 client uninstallation is completed"
    End If
  Loop
  ccmsetuplog.Close
End sub
'==========================Uninstall SCCM 2007 Client==========================

'==========================Removal of WDS and WEBDAV===========================
Sub Wdswebdavuninstall()
  Set wshshell=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
  Wscript.echo "Please wait while WEBDAV and WDS are being uninstalled"
  Wdsuninst=Wshshell.Run("cmd /c start /w ocsetup Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Services /Uninstall /quiet /norestart",0,True)
  uninstwdv=wshshell.Run("cmd /c start /w dism.exe /online /disable-feature /featurename=IIS-WebDAV /quiet /norestart",0,True)
  Wscript.sleep 100000
End Sub
'==========================Removal of WDS and WEBDAV===========================

'==========================Removal of folder Entries===========================
Sub Removalofflders()
  Set objfs=Createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  If objfs.folderexists("P:\Remoteinstall") Then
    objfs.Deletefolder "P:\Remoteinstall", True
  Else
    Wscript.echo "Remoteinsall folder is already deleted"
  End If
  If objfs.folderexists("P:\SMSPKG") Then
    objfs.Deletefolder "P:\SMSPKG", True
  Else
    Wscript.echo "SMSPKG folder is already deleted"
  End If
  If objfs.folderexists("P:\SMSPKGP$") Then
    objfs.Deletefolder "P:\SMSPKGP$", True
  Else
    Wscript.echo "SMSPKGP$ folder is already deleted"
  End If
  If objfs.folderexists("P:\SMSPKGSIG") Then
    objfs.Deletefolder "P:\SMSPKGSIG", True
  Else
    Wscript.echo "SMSPKGSIG folder is already deleted"
  End If
  If objfs.folderexists("P:\SMSSIG$") Then
    objfs.Deletefolder "P:\SMSSIG$", True
  Else
    Wscript.echo "SMSSIG$ folder is already deleted"
  End If
  If objfs.folderexists("C:\Windows\Ccmsetup") Then
    objfs.Deletefolder "C:\Windows\Ccmsetup", True 
  Else
    Wscript.echo "Ccmsetup folder is already deleted"
  End If
  If objfs.folderexists("C:\Windows\Syswow64\CCM") Then
    objfs.Deletefolder "C:\Windows\Syswow64\CCM", True
  Else
    Wscript.echo "CCM folder is already deleted"
  End If
  Wscript.echo "All stale folders and registry entries are removed"
End sub
'==========================Removal of folders entries==========================

'==========================Creation of NO_SMS_ON_DRIVE.SMS=====================
Sub Nosmsondrive()
  Set Wmiconnection=Getobject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & "."&"\root\cimv2")
  Set Drives=wmiconnection.execquery("Select * from win32_Logicaldisk where drivetype='3'")
  For each Drive in Drives
    If Not Drive.Deviceid="P:" then
      Set Objfso=createobject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
      If objfso.Fileexists("drive.deviceid\NO_SMS_ON_DRIVE.SMS") then
      Else
        Set smsondrive=objfso.createtextfile(drive.deviceid & "\NO_SMS_ON_DRIVE.SMS",True)
        smsondrive.close
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
'==========================Creation of NO_SMS_ON_DRIVE.SMS=====================
```

Comment: You should at least also share the exact errors you get.

Comment: Compliation error (59,1) which is ccmsetup sub and at last it says syntax error

Comment: From a different website, I came to know that, I can not run Sub routine from the middle of the script. The script that is already running should be closed before sub runs.. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

More likely you're getting the syntax error in line 57. You defined `Sub DeleteSbukeys` without an `End Sub` and VBScript doesn't allow nested procedure definitions.

```
...
Sub DeleteSubkeys(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPathm) 
  objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPathm, arrSubkeys 
  If IsArray(arrSubkeys) Then 
    For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
      DeleteSubkeys HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPathm & "\" & strSubkey 
    Next 
  End If 
  objRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPathm

  Call Nosmsondrive()
  Call Removalofflders()
  objRegistry.DeleteKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath
'<-- "End Sub" missing here
Sub ccmsetup()
  Set wshshell=wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
  Wscript.echo "Please Wait while SCCM 2007 client is getting uninstalled"
...
```